# Client config of WCF REST service is not being updated

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, config

I am using VS2012. My client configuration not updated when I have added service reference of WCF REST service. It is updating if I change binding to 'basicHttpBinding' in a WCF Service. Following is my WCF Service configuration.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior">

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

My WCF service is split into following projects.

1. WCFHost(has only .svc file with web.config mentioned above and uses following two projs)
2. WCFInterfaces (Class library, has no config file)
3. WCFImplementaions (Class library, has no config files)

I wonder if I am doing anything wrong with decoupling of WCF layers above and hence my client app unable to get config details when Service reference added.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear (if it is a question at all). Do you mean that when you update the Service Reference on your client project, your client configuration is not updated according to the server configuration? Then right-click the Service Reference, click Configure and check whether the URL points to the correct service. This URL is used to update the reference, not the one from your config. If this is not at all relevant: expand your question with the actual problems, the steps to reproduce and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have question to provide more details. URL points to the correct service.

Comment: Can I assume mexHttpBinding unable to provide for webHttpBinding?

Comment: Project structure and Web.config are as mention in problem description. Now, created a client console app, right clicked to add service reference, found my service onclick of 'Discover', added service reference. Opened app.config of client, validated if service reference elements are added. But I can't find them.. Then I went back to WCFHost project, updated endpoint binding to basicHttpBinding. Now back to client app and add service reference . I can see service reference elements were added. I want to understand why this inconsistent behaviour..

Comment: mexHTTpBiding will provide meta information to client to create a Proxy.

Comment: I now get what you mean and @Badin is correct. I know of no way to generate a REST client with WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio service reference does the magic because SOAP services provide WSDL. If you create a REST service, there is no WSDL and it will not work. The moment you switch to basic HTTP, it works because it is SOAP. You have to use HTTP libraries like HttpClient to talk to a REST endpoint.